# Something wrong with edit question button

Tags: support, edits

I clicked [edit on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238987/hoe-do-i-get-index-from-listboxitem-by-its-content) and I got below. It is coming repeatedly.

[image]

**Here's Developer console screen shot.**

[image]

**Console Error on Question page**

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the dev console? I can't reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)`. Updated it in question

Comment: When you went into the question, there was not a pending edit. By the time you clicked the button, there was. (The edit button is greyed out for me, and hovering says there is a pending edit.) Refresh the question page and the edit option should be greyed out.

Comment: @Kendra When I clicked on edit, it shows me `There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.` Now it's grayed out for me too

Comment: Are you getting this error again after refreshing? Is there anything in the console after refreshing (but before clicking)?

Comment: When you [load the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238987/hoe-do-i-get-index-from-listboxitem-by-its-content), is there anything in the dev console (before clicking or doing anything on the page)?

Comment: @Oded I refreshed the page, still I'm getting blank screen with `There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.` But no error in console

Comment: I am asking for when you load the question, not the edit page.

Comment: Which page are you refreshing? The question page or the edit page?

Comment: @Oded I'm getting some error on question page in console. I've updated it in question.

Comment: Those errors appear to be due to your use of an ad blocker.

Comment: Now that the pending edit is through, you should be able to click the edit button just fine, Rahul, and get taken to the edit page.

Comment: @Oded I've ad blocker here

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: @Oded But what about this error. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)`

Comment: This is designed behaviour. While there is a pending suggested edits, the edit service for the question is not available to yourself (until you hit 2000 rep, when you can approve suggested edits).

Comment: Thank you not aware of  this.

Comment: @Oded Little bit strange right. Getting 503 (Service Unavailable) error as a part of design behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pending edit on the question, and you cannot submit another suggested edit until that has cleared.

What happened was you opened the question. While you were reading, another <2k rep user or an annonymous user submitted and edit. Since you did not refresh, clicking the button took you to the page telling you that you cannot edit. After navigating back to the page via a new page click or a refresh, the edit button became unavailable, as that is an action you now cannot take.

If you had 2k rep at the time this occurred, which is why Oded couldn't reproduce the error, instead of the error page, you would have been taken to the "edit review" page for that post to review the pending edit. Since you have less than 2k rep at this time, you were instead shown an error because there is nothing you can do until the edit has cleared.

I would be willing to bet the reason it didn't become unavailable before is you were navigating to the question via the back button, which was not refreshing the state of the page.

Comment: I know the stuff about editing question. What about the error I got while editing question.

Comment: The error is because there is a pending edit and you cannot submit a new one until that clears. When you clicked "edit", the server then saw that you _couldn't_ edit due to another pending edit. This is why the button is now unavailable: _it is an action that you cannot take._ The error tells you exactly what is wrong. _"There is a pending suggested edit in the queue"_ and because of this, _you cannot edit._ The 503 error in the console is correct, that particular service is currently unavailable to you because of the pending edit.

Comment: @Kendra - when clicking the edit link when a suggested edit is pending, the OP should not be getting a blank page with some text.

Comment: @Oded If the OP is less than 2k rep, they shouldn't even be able to click the button when an edit is pending. I certainly can't, loading the page _after_ the edit is pending. I've seen this particular error message before myself.

Comment: Fair point - didn't consider that. Thanks.