# Strange bug with suggesting an edit?

Tags: bug, edits

I was working on editing some posts from new users (not from review), and I started getting this page when I clicked on the edit link:

[image]

Why is that showing up? In the past, if an edit was in review for a post, the edit button would be grayed out, but it's not:

[image]

What is causing this?

Here is what I am running on my computer:

**OS**

- OS X Yosemite version 10.11

**Browser**

- Google Chrome version 47.0.2526.73

**Extensions**

- AdBlock version 2.45
- Google Docs version 0.9
- Google Docs Offline version 1.1
- Google Mail Checker version 4.4.0
- New Tab Redirect version 3.1.4 (not enabled)
- Print Friendly & PDF version 2.3
- Stack Exchange Deleted Answer Manager version 1.4 (not enabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the issue is gone now. I think it was just a glitch.

Comment: Actually, it's not a glitch. There was no pending edit when you went to the question, but before you clicked edit one was submitted. When _you_ clicked edit, it was still pending and you therefore got an error informing you there was one. The edit is no longer pending, hence you are no longer getting the error.

Comment: @Kendra. Ah, thanks. Great answer!

Comment: There was a similar situation, and I posted [an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294280/2607247) to that one.

Comment: No problem. It's definitely a bit jarring to get that page with no formatting and just text, so I can definitely see where you thought it was a bug