# Cannot edit a post. Is this a bug or something I'm not aware of?

Tags: discussion, edits

I went to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605582/html-does-not-load-till-graph-api-calls-are-executed) while doing question triage, but the edit button is currently grayed out. Other questions I've looked at after and before have the edit functionality available.

Is this a bug or something I'm missing? The only thing I can think of is that it's pending an edit from someone else. If that's the case, shouldn't there be some indication that's the case so users know?

Comment: You're right, there was a [pending edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12006675) from someone else, which you can't see until 2,000 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a suggested edit pending on the post.

For those of us with less than 2,000 reputation, if an edit is suggested on a post and is in the process of being reviewed, we cannot edit the question further. For this reason, the button is disabled. If you hover over the button while it's disabled, you'll get a tooltip stating that there is a pending edit.

For users with more than 2,000 reputation, instead of editing they get a link to the suggested edit review. Their edit button is not disabled, but changed. They'll also see a `(1)` next to the button, signalling that there is a pending suggested edit for the post.

There is a way to get around the button changing, by manually changing the URL. However, users with less than 2,000 reputation, they will be taken to a mostly blank page with some error text, as seen in [this Meta question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294274/something-wrong-with-edit-question-button) If a user with more than 2,000 reputation does this and submits an edit from this page, it will reject the suggested edit as "conflicting with a subsequent edit", provided the suggested edit is still pending when the edit is submitted.

The edit has been approved, so you should now be able to click the edit button on that question.