# Page for editing a deleted post for users with less than 10k reputation

Tags: feature-request, edits, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

When a user with less than 10k reputation* tries to directly access the edit page of a post that's been removed, this message appears:

> This post is deleted and cannot be edited.

And it looks like this:

[image: error message for edit page]

*Update: Same page is shown for unregistered users.*

---

Should this be changed to something else? Maybe at least add a link to the home?

It feels like this page is not up to the level of SO and very non-production looking.

---

<sub><sup>* I assume that's only for <10k since 10k+ users can see deleted posts.</sup></sub>

Comment: (10k+ users get a normal "edit" page)

Comment: It was the simplest code that could work.... and has never been revisited after that ...

Comment: This page is unstyled because nobody should ever see it. If you can't edit a post, you also can't see the edit *link* for a post, so there's very little value in making this experience any nicer. The only people seeing this are those editing URLs to land on pages they shouldn't.

Comment: We already have a page for trying to view deleted posts, so we can probably just use that here instead.

Comment: @meagar Open post -> click edit -> post gets deleted before new page loads -> get this page. Seems plausible, albeit rare (less rare if something goes wrong on the client side to prevent the page from updating automatically).

Comment: @Dukeling Viewing deleted posts is a normal thing. Posts have permalinks that get shared. Viewing the *edit* page for a deleted post is not a comparable case, it's very abnormal for a user to wind up on the edit page for a post they can no longer edit, especially since the edit page isn't actually used by default. Editing a question happens inline on the "show" page, the edit is spawned via JavaScript.

Comment: A 404 page would be good (like for the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47511748/timeline)). By the way, I think that a 403 page (forbidden) would be more suitable for deleted posts (both the question page, the edit page, the timeline, etc) since the pages exist, they're just not accessible to low reputation users.

Comment: @meagar Editing inline is a privilege. Users below (I think) [2k](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) edit on a separate page.

Comment: It's a plain-text response, so it's probably meant to be a response to an AJAX request.

Comment: Note that I'm not saying _hey, let's build the most amazing page in the planet_, I'm just saying that this doesn't look like a production-looking page and it could be enhanced. Production code _should_ also handle 'places where people shouldn't be', as long as those places exist, imho.

Comment: @meagar Sorry but that’s kind of a lazy attitude from you there. There are so many things that users shouldn’t see when everything works correctly; but those things usually are still be prepared for the possibility. – Just say that you never styled this because it never occurred to you that people could end up in that situation. But please don’t attempt to explain that this is intentional… :S

Comment: @pole I don’t work for SO and I have never written a line of code for it. I have nothing to do with the content of that page.

Comment: @meagar I wasn’t saying that but your responses still give off that impression that you, as a mod on behalf of SO, are defending the behavior as designed.

Comment: @poke I am, I see nothing wrong with it

Comment: @meagar Perhaps when you have time, you could leave an answer to the question stating why you don't think it should change, to allow the community to vote on the proposal.

Comment: @meagar About your: *"This page is unstyled because nobody should ever see it."* - 10k+ members can still access a deleted post (and go into edit mode but probably can't save it) by adding it to their Favorites before it ever gets deleted and for any reason. So what you said doesn't really hold much water. If it's not to be seen by anyone, then make it so that even higher rep members can't access also it if it's that such an issue/a big deal. I do agree on the fact that it's an unstyled way to show it's deleted (and can't be edited), so yeah... it's best to leave well enough alone, as it were.

Comment: @Dukeling They get the same page, but their edit won't be saved automatically, rather is becomes a "suggested edits" review task.

Comment: @Dukeling [My pleasure :-)](https://i.imgur.com/QJL1X1y.png).

Comment: @Dukeling As you can see, there is no difference.

Comment: @peterh The one is inline ([shows the score, comments, answers, etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUROb.png)), the other is [on a separate page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjrYQ.png) (similar for low-rep users and those not logging in).

Comment: @Dukeling You are right! Thanks! Honestly, I never noticed the difference, but yes there is! :-)

Answer (score 8):

I have to side with [FirstOne](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359888/page-for-editing-a-deleted-post-for-users-with-less-than-10k-reputation#comment535406_359888):

> ...I'm not saying hey, let's build the most amazing page in the planet, I'm just saying that this doesn't look like a production-looking page and it could be enhanced. Production code should also handle 'places where people shouldn't be', as long as those places exist, imho.

It's more a matter of good style than one of practicality, so the number of people who actually view this page isn't relevant.

The fix could be as trivial as redirecting to the page that already exists for viewing the deleted question itself: [example for <10k only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323246).

I think handling this edge case is good form, and could be taken care of with minimal effort.

Comment: +1 because it probably would be easy to just redirect to that deleted post page.

Answer (score 3):

I donno, I kinda like that page. It's got a lot going for it:

- the message is unambiguous and to the point - there's no confusion as to *why* you're not getting the editor that you expected.
- it loads quickly, saving precious data on my capped mobile connection.
- it respects my browser's zoom settings and doesn't override the default font size that I've specified.
- there are no ads, background images or superfluous chrome to distract me from the precious content of the page.

Honestly, I'd like to see more pages adopt this styling.

Comment: Let's turn SO into [a real website](http://motherfuckingwebsite.com/). [nsfw - swearing]

Comment: Well, [we have at least one other like this on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294274/something-wrong-with-edit-question-button) so maybe someday you'll get your wish, Shog.

Answer (score -3):

I would have to agree with [meagar's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359888/page-for-editing-a-deleted-post-for-users-with-less-than-10k-reputation?cb=1#comment535378_359888):

> This page is unstyled because nobody should ever see it. If you can't
>   edit a post, you also can't see the edit link for a post, so there's
>   very little value in making this experience any nicer. The only people
>   seeing this are those editing URLs to land on pages they shouldn't.

As a normal unaffiliated user of SO, I think that unstyled page is just fine for an event that is almost impossible to happen anyways. It would take some extraordinary circumstances to see that message: Either the post gets deleted within milliseconds after someone clicks the link, or someone bookmarks the edit page for some reason, which is unlikely.

I think that time is better spent on other areas of SO.

Comment: Your comment about priorities (time better spent) inspired me to open [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360053/should-a-feature-request-be-voted-based-on-its-priority). Just letting you know as I think it's only fair ;)