# Should we update the 'deleted-answers' tag description?

Tags: feature-request, tags

**Background**

We have the [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions) tag with the following description:

> refers to all questions deleted from Stack Overflow. The tag "specific-question" should also be used when referencing a specific question that has been deleted.

But when it comes to [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers), this is the description:

> is the tag to use for any questions related to deleted answers specifically.

---

**Elaborating**

The [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions) seems fair enough, as it relates to *all questions in general*. But for [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers), it *almost* seems like we are talking about a specific answer.

I can understand the meaning after thinking about it: it's saying that it's specific to answers (still in general) for any question. But maybe we could make it a little less ambiguous and expand the description.

<sup><sup>I know this looks like a bit of a stretch, but I was kinda confused at first cause my previous [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359888/page-for-editing-a-deleted-post-for-users-with-less-than-10k-reputation) is not for a specific answer.. after some thinking, I was able to understand the reason behind the tag. (Could be because English is not my first language) Anyways, this is my..</sup></sup>

---

**Suggestion** *(based on the 'deleted-questions' tag)*

> refers to all answers deleted from Stack Overflow. The tag "specific-question" should also be used when referencing a specific answer that has been deleted.

*I kept 'specific-question' because an answer can only be posted for a question. But it could be changed to 'specific-answer' if it fits better.*

Comment: Why are you asking it here, and not proposing an edit through the [Edit Tag Info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/222)  button?

Comment: Well, first because I didn't know about that xD.. Second, even if I had enough reputation, I still don't think it's up to _me_ to make that decision. But since I don't have 20k yet, I'll try it and link this question, then. ty @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: You're not making that decision alone, and you do have enough rep for it. It will end up in the review queue, where high-rep members can review, revise and approve or decline your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an edit suggestion to change the tag description to:

> refers to all answers deleted from Stack Overflow. The tag "specific-answer" should also be used when referencing a specific answer that has been deleted.

It has been [Approved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17222).

Comment: So I guess the answer to the question is _yes_. I was hoping to see maybe more input about other options, but it's fine.